# Download a file from a folder in c# windows application.

Tags: c#, windows

I have a c# windows application. In the application I have a "files" folder in which i have put an excel file. i created a form and applied a linklabel. Now i want to download that file to my computer by clicking on that linklabel. I have tried on internet and mostly i get this code

```
using (WebClient client = new WebClient())

client.DownloadFile("http://csharpindepth.com/About.aspx", 
                    @"c:\Users\Jon\Test\foo.txt");
```

But my problem is my file is not on internet and its in the same application

Thank you

Comment: If you need simple File I/O, use the File class. for reading text use File.ReadAllText and for reading other kinds of data use File.ReadAllBytes.

Comment: what are you trying to do with the file? Your file already on your machine. Why you need to download it? I feel, this is bogus question. If you want an answer, you need to fix your question. Because as it is, it will be impossible to resolve your issue

Comment: i did this but still not downloading file                                                 string Pth = System.Windows.Forms.Application.StartupPath + "/Formatfile.xlsx";
            File.ReadAllText(Pth);

Comment: My Question in very simple. my file is in "files folder" of the application. i want to download this file to system. means when i will generate .exe in the end. this file should get download from some form.

Comment: You seem to be confused about the term "download". "To download a file" means to pull a file from a **different** computer/server through a network/internet -- that is not the case here. If you have your file already on your computer then you want to **copy** it from "files" folder to some other folder. Use [File.Copy(...)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.copy.aspx) for this purpose

Comment: @user2193729 you need to change your question radically. From your comment your question should be, "how to read excel" file. In this case, you will probably find an answer already. So, to get a good answer, you need to post your code and point, `// here I want to do this`. Judging from your comment you want not download but read your file. Usually, it is done like this: You have an executable `bin` folder and in it you have `files` folder. Path Access: `string filePath = Path.Combine(Application.ExecutablePath, "files", myFilename)`. This will work independently where application installed

Answer (score -1):

Try this Code

```
var saveFileDialog = new SaveFileDialog();    
saveFileDialog.DefaultExt = "xls";    
saveFileDialog.Filter = "Excel files (*.xls)|*.xls |All files (*.*)|*.*";

if (saveFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)    
{    
    const string MyFileName = "myExcelFile.xls";

    string execPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase);    
    var filePath = Path.Combine(execPath, MyFileName);

    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application app = new Application();    
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook book = app.Workbooks.Open(filePath);

    book.SaveAs(saveFileDialog.FileName); //Save   
    book.Close();
}
```

Comment: First, please format your post correctly (half your code is in code format, half isn't, and the "try this" statement is in code when it shouldn't be). Second, please explain how you feel this answers the question. It just looks like a standard excel interop block to me. I did the edit for you, please understand how to do this in the future.

Comment: The above sample is for Windows Application

Comment: No kidding. I still don't know what the OP is asking, so an explanation of how your answer accomplishes what you think he is asking would be appreciated.

Comment: 1).Add the excel file to your Project (Add -> Existing Item).
2).Right Click the added Excel File, go to Properties
3).Set Build Action to Content
4).Set Copy to Output Directory as Copy Always or Copy If Newer

Comment: @HiralNayak its working in my project for excel file to download on link this way i alredy done in past for window application thats good :)